# I never would've imagined that it would've brought me to here

Tags: grammar

> They're gonna kill you. Just like they killed my parents. I was, uh, five when it happened. No one knew who did it. That's why I became a cop to find out. I never would've imagined that it would've brought me to here, but it has. I am not leaving this city until I prove it.

The above is an excerpt from a script of an American TV show.

I am very confused about this sentence "I never would've imagined that it would've brought me to here". Are two "would have done" structures in this sentence all subjunctive? If so, could you add an if-clause?

By the way, what's the difference between the two sentences below?

> 1. I never would've imagined that it would've brought me to here.
> 2. I never would've imagined that it would bring me to here.

Comment: I guess that stylistically, it's the needless repetition of the word "would" that makes the sentence sound like spoken, unedited speech. If I were writing the thought in my own voice, not supplying words to a character, I would say "I never imagined that it would bring me here," a gramatically simpler way of stating the message that seems to have been intended.

Answer (score 1):

- No, they're not [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive). Both use the [conditional mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood).
- Yes, you can add an *if* clause:

  > I never would've imagined that it would've brought me to here **if I became a cop**, but it has.

There is practically no difference in meaning between these two sentences:

> 1. I never would've imagined that it would've brought me to here.
> 2. I never would've imagined that it would bring me to here.

In the first sentence, the speaker is speaking about the **past**: *that it **would've brought** me to here*. In the past, the speaker was brought here.

In the second sentence, the speaker is speaking about the **present**: *that it **would bring** me to here*. The speaker is here now, in the present.

Both sentences imply the other.